# Cannot find template location: classpath:/templates/

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

I have included the html files under src/main/resources/templates folder in my Spring Boot App. Yet I get the Whitelabel Error in my local host and "Cannot find template location: classpath:/templates/ (please add some templates or check your Thymeleaf configuration)" in the console. Can anyone please help?

I wasn't even able to call a single html page.

Comment: If you could also post what you have done so far like which dependency of thymeleaf is added, any extra configuration done, etc., it would be helpful to answer

Comment: I have included the following dependencies: Web, Thymeleaf, JPA, H2

Comment: Can you share more details on what you do?

Answer (score 0):

Run `maven install` twice (!); then it works.